# Chromium open a file:// url, in kiosk mode, but remember cookies

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I live in a country where the internet is not stable. If I make chromium start up in kiosk mode and there is no internet, it shows a blank page, and never tries again to load it (if internet is available at start up, but does down after the initial start up, then it will retry later).

To load my website, I load a local webpage, which then pings a common api to find out if the internet is up. Once the internet is confirmed to be up and running, then I load the required page. The website requires cookies to be saved between reboots.

However my testing has shown if I have kiosk mode on, and open chromium at a `file://url...`, then it does not remember the cookie. If I change to the actual url, then it does remember the cookie. It seems I can only have kiosk mode, or the no internet page loader, how does one get both?

Heres my current command (formated for easy reading):

```
chromium-browser 
    --kiosk 
    --disable-session-crashed-bubble 
    --disable-infobars 
    --user-data-dir=/home/pi/browser/ 
    file:///home/pi/my_page_loader.html?fwd_url=https://www.mywebsite.com/
```

How to start Chrome in Kiosk mode and load a file url, and remember cookies for a given domain or any domain.

Answer (score 0):

In the end instead of forwarding to the required page, in JS one can call `window.close()` to close the browser, which then continues the script, which launches the browser again but this time at the URL directly so it stores the cookies:

```
chromium-browser --kiosk "file:///home/pi/my_page_loader.html?ping_url=https://www.myproject.com"
chromium-browser --kiosk --user-data-dir=/home/pi/kiosk/ "https://www.myproject.com"
```